How do I edit the indentation used when serializing a yaml string using yamldotnet in C#?
I managed to generate a YAML string. The default indentation is 2 characters but i need it to be 4 characters. As this is required by the application that will be processing this data. But I have not managed to succeed to achieve this.
Here is my code:
 var yamlSerializer = new SerializerBuilder()
     .Build();

 string yaml;
 using (var writer = new StringWriter())
 {
     var _settings = new EmitterSettings();
     Console.WriteLine(_settings.BestIndent);
     _settings.WithBestIndent(4);
     var _emitter = new Emitter(writer, _settings);
     yamlSerializer.Serialize(_emitter, dictionary);
     yaml = writer.ToString();
 }

 Console.WriteLine(yaml);

Here the output:
cars:
  bmw:
    model: 1 series
    catagory: coupe
    year: 2008
  nissan:
    model: 300zx
    catagory: hatchback
    year: 1996
  toyota:
    model: 4runner
    catagory: suv
    year: 2015
  audi:
    model: a8
    catagory: sedan
    year: 2017

And it should be like this:
cars:
    bmw:
        model: 1 series
        catagory: coupe
        year: 2008
    nissan:
        model: 300zx
        catagory: hatchback
        year: 1996
    toyota:
        model: 4runner
        catagory: suv
        year: 2015
    audi:
        model: a8
        catagory: sedan
        year: 2017


You need to write _settings = _settings.WithBestIndent(4);. The With*() methods doesn't change the (current) settings object, they return a new settings object with the adjusted property.

Mind that this requirement of the receiving software is in clear violation of the yaml spec : https://yaml.org/spec/1.2.2/#chapter-6-structural-productions Maybe consider raising this issue as a bug  report.

@Progman Thank you for the solution. It works!

As stated in the comments by Progman. The WithBestIndent() method does not change the current settings object.
Here the adjusted code that gives the desired result:
string yaml;
 using (var writer = new StringWriter())
 {
     var _settings = new EmitterSettings();
     Console.WriteLine(_settings.BestIndent);
     _settings = _settings.WithBestIndent(4);
     var _emitter = new Emitter(writer, _settings);
     yamlSerializer.Serialize(_emitter, dictionary);
     yaml = writer.ToString();
 }

 Console.WriteLine(yaml);

